# How to insert image in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, blob

> I used these lines of code  but in the table it is showing null

```
create table Picture( imageID integer primary key, image blob);
insert into Picture values(1, LOAD_FILE('D:\\flower.gif'));
```

> `select * from Picture;`

Please someone help me to resolve this problem. I'm using MySQL. You can give me solution for MySQL and SQL Developer also.

Comment: Your syntax looks correct.  Are you certain that the path to the file is also correct?  And when you say "showing null" what do you mean?  What does `SELECT * FROM Picture WHERE imageID = 1` show you?

Comment: Yes the file path is correct. Instead of showing me the picture it's showing null in table.

Comment: You might need to escape backslashes. Or use slashes instead.

Comment: I'm in Windows 10. If I escape blackshlashes wont it show error? because that is how a path is defined in Windows. I don't know I maybe wrong Im trying with your syntax

Comment: Is the MySQL server running on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

[The Fine Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html) explains:

> The FILE privilege gives you permission to read and write files on the server host using ... the LOAD_FILE() function. A user who has the FILE privilege can read any file on the server host that is either world-readable or readable by the MySQL server.

You didn't share any SHOW GRANT output with us.

Consider issuing a GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'X'@'Y' command.

Also, if your connect string refers to a machine other than `localhost`, you will need to verify the .gif file is readable on that server machine, rather than on your client machine. The uid that mysqld is running under is the one that needs filesystem read permission.